# exit status 128 fatal: missing blob object

Tags: git

Sorry if this has been posted before

I moved files from a child to a parent directory

Then I got a problem trying to push them, so I did:

`git remote add origin`

`git push --force --set-upstream origin main`

But this gets the error:

`ref main:: Error in git rev-list --objects --ignore-missing --stdin --: exit status 128 fatal: missing blob object '0011d5f42a30d158b68f986436d3a2bd331b72de'`

I don't know what this means, what does it mean?

`git branch -a` gives:

```
* main
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```